# How to select a word which contains a previous word?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, positive-lookbehind

I'm trying to select a word that is on the second line, but first I need to check if there is a word on the first line, regex [example](https://regex101.com/r/pmKDL2/1):

```
(?<=isaac)select
```

this is the text

```
abcdefgisaachijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefgselecthijklmno
```

Just to clarify my idea a little

[image]

Why doesn't this regex work when `isaac` precedes `select`?

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try: `(?<=isaac)([\S\s]*)select` this will capture everything between isaac and select.

Comment: @user3783243 I need to select the word "select" and not select the word "isaac". But to select I need to check if there is the word "isaac" before "select"

Comment: oh yes, it did! your regex and @iPaat's worked, thanks!

Comment: Your title does not agree with your actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `issac` so it is in a non-capture group, and allow for anything until `select` is present.

```
(?s)(?:isaac.*)(select)
```

The `(?s)` modifies the `.` operator so it allows for new lines as well.

https://regex101.com/r/qPQH25/1

Comment: Your regex matches `"My name is isaac m. newton, let's see if select is \non the next line"`. Also I don't understand the point of having `isasc.*` in a non-capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Since the two words are given there is no point to *select* the word in the second line; it is enough to determine if the first word is in the first line and the second word is in the second line.

The needed regular expression is simple:

```
.*isaac.*\n.*select
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/bIRq6i/1)